# Configuring UCC GoDaddy SSL Certificate in IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5, godaddy, ucc

**PLATFORM**

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server with IIS7.5 and we host a number of our client's websites.

**OBJECTIVE**

We need to configure two domains: Acme.co.za and Contoso.com to make use of an UCC GoDaddy certificate issued for both these domains. We've checked the certificate and it's correct.

**STEPS TAKEN**

We followed instructions from various bloggers and did the following: 
1. Installed the certificate in the Certificates MMC snap-in
2. Completed the certificate request in IIS, then
3. We assigned the certificate to the first domain Acme.co.za by adding an HTTPS binding and using the newly installed certificate
4. In the command prompt we used the following commands to configure the host headers for each site:
appcmd set site /site.name:"Acme" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:433:www.acme.co.za']

appcmd set site /site.name:"Contoso" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:433:www.contoso.com']

Each command responded successfully with SITE object "Acme" changed and SITE object "Contoso" changed

**PROBLEM**

On the first run when we browsed to https://www.acme.co.za it worked fine. Browsing to https://www.contoso.com just redirected back to https://www.acme.co.za

Now on the second attempt https://www.acme.co.za works fine, but https://www.contoso.com simply redirects back to http://www.contoso.com without the (S) in the protocol section of the address. So now it's not redirecting to the first domain at least, but it's redirecting back onto itself with no SSL certificate being used.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIs can only respond to https once for each IP and on that port you can only have a  single app with its cert. It doesn't work the same way as http where you can have many urls associated with port 80.

How have you configured two https servers - do you have a separate IP/interface for each one?

If you don't have a separate ip for each, what you've described above would be normal.